# error: Cannot change ACTION parameter in OPEN statement

Tags: fortran

I have the problem in the title with the following Fortran 95 code:

More or less the code consists in the calculation of the points that are in the `print*,` statement doing interpolation. I tried putting the `open` and `close` statement outside the first loop. When I do that I get this error:

```
At line 23 of file 7.f95 (Unit 1 "ejeY1.txt")
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

The file ejeY1.txt has these data

```
0.00 0.00
0.50 5.00
1.00 10.00
1.50 15.00
2.00 20.00
2.50 25.00
```

the code it is below

```
program ej7
use mcf_interpoli
real,dimension(1:6)::x,y
real,dimension(1:5)::temporaly,xv
real,dimension(1:3)::array_y,array_x
real::xp,yp,err
integer::i,j,k



array_y=(/1.20,2.40,0.82/)
array_x=(/0.70,1.60,0.65/)

do i=1,size(array_y)
    open(unit=1,status="old",action="read",file="ejeY1.txt")
    open(unit=2,status="old",action="read",file="ejeY2.txt")
    open(unit=3,status="old",action="read",file="ejeY3.txt")
    open(unit=4,status="old",action="read",file="ejeY4.txt")
    open(unit=8,status="old",action="read",file="ejeY5.txt")
    open(unit=7,status="old",action="read",file="ejeX.txt")
    do k=1,4
        do j=1,6
            read(unit=k,fmt=*) x(j), y(j)
        end do
        call polint(x,y,size(x),array_y(i),yp,err)
        temporaly(k)=yp
    end do

    do k=1,6
        read(unit=8,fmt=*) x(k), y(k)
    end do
    call polint(x,y,size(x),array_y(i),yp,err)
    temporaly(5)=yp

    do j=1,5
        read(unit=7,fmt=*) xv(j)
    end do
    do j=1,size(array_x)
        call polint(xv,temporaly,size(xv),array_x(j),yp,err)
        if (array_y(i)==1.20 .and. array_x(j)==0.7) then
            print*,"El valor para (0.7,1.20) es: ", yp
        else if (array_y(i)==2.40 .and. array_x(j)==1.60) then
            print*,"El valor para (1.60,2.40) es: ",yp
        else if (array_y(i)==0.82 .and. array_x(j)==0.65) then
            print*, "El valor para (0.65,0.82) es: ",yp
        end if
    end do
    do j=1,4
        close(i)
    end do
    do j=7,8
        close(i)
    end do
end do



end program ej7
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. The message tells you to compile the code with `-ftrace=frame` or `-ftrace=full`. Do that and re-run the code.

Comment: I suspect you want close( j ) rather than close( i ) near the end of the program

Comment: BTW the code is not below as you definitely don't include the mcf_interpoli module, and possibly polint as well